# C++ program cannot find latex command with system() function call

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, latex

I am writing a C++ program which has to automatically generate some data to be used by students in an integrated exercise. I have already exported this data to .tex files and would also like the C++ program to be able to compile these tex files automatically.

Usually I would compile tex files from the command line by doing the following:

```
$ latex file.tex
$ latex file.tex
$ dvipdf file.dvi
```

So I tried doing the following in my C++ code (directory and filename are both strings):

```
//Move to the location where I created the files
string mycommand = "cd ";
mycommand += directory;
system(mycommand.c_str());
//Compile latex
mycommand = "latex " + filename + "_main.tex";
system(mycommand.c_str());
system(mycommand.c_str());
//Create .pdf
mycommand = "dvipdf " + filename + "_main.dvi";
system(mycommand.c_str());
```

Which then produces the following error message on the terminal output:

```
sh: latex: command not found
sh: latex: command not found
sh: dvipdf: command not found
```

I have searched this online but I have failed to find a solution for this problem, though I believe it is likely to be something very simple.

I am working on OSX and have the following version of latex installed:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dude, `man 2 chdir`...

Comment: What do you mean? I'm sorry but I am quite inexperienced when it comes to things like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the path to the programs `latex` and `dvipdf` needs to be in your `PATH` environment variable.

Second, the calls of the shell via `system` are totally independent (in fact a new instance of the shell is started each time). So if you switch the directory in one, this does not affect the others. Switch instead the current directory of your program via:

```
chdir(directory.c_str())
```

You need for this

```
#include <cunistd>
using namespace std;
```

at the beginning of the file.

Please note that `system` calls with command lines depending on input parameters can be easily exploited to run arbitrary commands if the parameters (in your case the filename) are not carefully checked. As you do not have quotes, the program fails if there are e.g. whitespaces in the filename.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I had no idea what I was doing wrong, but you have set me on the right track!

For the change of directory I had to include <unistd.h> instead, but this was easy to find. 

The security issue will not be an issue for now, since I will be the only person with access to the program, but good to know - I will keep it in mind for future software.

For dummies like me, changing the PATH variable is done like this:
PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin
where usr/texbin is the location of the executable.